# Does SQL Server support restoring to a point in time down to the millisecond?

Tags: sql-server-2008, restore

Using the Management Studio GUI, I am only able to restore a database to a point in time down to the second.  Is this just a limitation of the GUI or if I use a script will it restore to the millisecond I specify?

I'm trying to do it with a script and it 'seems' like it's ignoring the millisecond but unfortunately the date value I'm comparing to is, unfortunately, not necessarily the exact time the record was written so I just want to rule out any possibility that the problem could be because of a limitation of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is a limitation of SSMS.  When using T-SQL you can control it to the three millisecond mark.  The input is done via a datetime variable so it's bound by the normal datatime data type rules which is precise to the 3 milliseconds.